# Can't connect addTextChangedListener with TextWatcher

Tags: java, textwatcher, addtextchangedlistener

I am new to forum and Java.

I got stucked when trying to get my TextView updated when entering numbers on my EditText. I want this class MyTextWatcher connect with convertMoney(); and do the calculations there (I'll add more stuff later)

```
private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        convertMoney();
    }
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
}

EditText text;

private void convertMoney() {

    text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount);
    text.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher());

    double value = Double.parseDouble(text.getText().toString)

    double totalSave =  * 17;
    TextView totalSaveText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    totalSaveText.setText("" + totalSave);
}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: And what is the problem ? Please see [ask]

Answer (score 1):

The lines:

```
text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount);
text.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher());
```

Should be probably somewhere else. You add your TextWatcher inside the method that is called by the TextWatcher, so it's never called. Put it to `onCreate()` or to some other appropriate place.